# jquery masonry/isotope like plugin that grows / shrinks elements based on importance

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry, jquery-isotope

Does anyone know of a jquery plugin that would stack elements like masonry or isotope and displays bigger / smaller elements based on importance? Could not find a way to do this with either of these mentioned plugins. Is there any plugin out there that does this ?

**edit:**

tried to make an image of what i need, numbers represent different weights that would make the rectangles fill more of less of their parent container.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a plugin that does this out of the box, but you could take a tagcloud plugin and modify the CSS to make boxes bigger and smaller, rather than just the font size.

The drop that into a 960 grid system or any other masonry, and it will flow columns decently well. Everything might not line up on the right edge though.

To line things up on the right edge would take some more complex math than simply making things bigger and smaller. Currently the question does not specify how you want things to line up or display. Simply stacking elements is way easier than doing what isotope does.

Please clarify.

[Edit]

Oh, yeah, there is totally a plugin for that: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063582

"A treemap recursively subdivides area into rectangles; the area of any node in the tree corresponds to its value. This example uses color to encode different packages of the Flare visualization toolkit. Treemap design invented by Ben Shneiderman. Squarified algorithm by Bruls, Huizing and van Wijk. Data courtesy Jeff Heer."

Not the easiest thing to build, but this one was made with D3: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery

Comment: added an image that illustrates what i need. Your idea is actually cool, although, like you mentioned, it could be hard to line up stuff. When i say stack, i mean doing what isotope does, not with floats.

Comment: Thanks m8, thats exactly what i needed, only down side is that it depends on d3, but it's doable.